# Can I create an ambari file view instance if hadoop is not on same node as Ambari-server?

Tags: hadoop, ambari

So my cluster is set up this way:

- node1 - ambari-server
- node2 hdpmasternode (has ambari agent)
- node3
  hdpdatanode1 (has abmari agent)
- node4 hdpdatanode2 (has ambari agent)

Can I still set up a file view instance on ambari, even if I don't have hdfs installed on my ambari node? Will Ambari see hdfs files with this setup?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it out myself, but my best guess is that you can.
The Files View jar will be running on the same host as Ambari server, which may or may not have an HDFS client.

I believe Files View uses WebHDFS (since it asks for a [URI](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.0.0/bk_ambari_views_guide/content/creating_the_files_view_instance.html)). Providing the correct WebHDFS URI in addition to some proxy user setting should allow the View to access the files.